# Teams Join Meeting using joinwebUrl not working for Users not in organization

Tags: reactjs, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

For the users in the organization I am able to see users in the participants list when I am opening link JoinWebUrl with `windows.open(JoinWebUrl)` generating from `client.api('/me/onlineMeetings')` but if I am adding some participants that are not users in my organization as a attendee I am unable to see those users as Attendee. Can anyone help with this.

```
    const client = await getAuthenticatedClient(accessToken);
    const onlineMeeting = {
        startDateTime: '2021-05-31T17:33:30.8546353-07:00',
        endDateTime: "2021-05-31T18:33:30.8546353-07:00",
        subject: 'HelpaaS Expert Call',
        // externalId: '07aa75f6-6fc8-4fdc-bed1-9dab78f899c0',
        participants: {
            attendees: [
                {"@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.meetingParticipantInfo"},
                {
                    identity: {
                        user: {
                            id: '07aa75f6-6fc8-4fdc-bed1-9dab78f899c0',//id.AAD_UserGuid,
                            displayName : 'Sanjeev Gupta'//id.DisplayName
                        }
                    },
                    role: 'attendee',
                    upn: 'sanjeev.gupta@softobiz.com'//id.Mail
                }
            ]
            // "organizer": {
            //     "identity": {
            //         "user": {
            //             id: '07aa75f6-6fc8-4fdc-bed1-9dab78f899c0',//id.AAD_UserGuid,
            //             displayName : id.DisplayName
            //         }
            //     }
            // }
        }
        // "isBroadcast": true
    };
    
   let response =  client.api('/me/onlineMeetings')
        .post(onlineMeeting);
        response.then(async data=>{
            console.log(data,"Call the user now");
            // window.open(data.joinWebUrl)
    }
```

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Could you please try using microsoftTeams.executeDeepLink(/*deepLink*/), instead of using window.open(). Try if that helps

Comment: Are you still facing the issue? Could you please share an update?

Comment: Yes, basically I am not creating any teams app so I don't have this microsftTeams object in order to executeLink to work. I am using MSAL library and graph APIs. If what you said is possible in react please guide me.
Thanks

Comment: You can use join url in the card action and when user clicks on the button he will be redirected to the meeting. You can send card using Graph API could you please check [Send message containing cards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-3-send-message-containing-cards). Try if that helps.

Comment: Thats not actually what I want I want to give call functionality to users but via teams and callculate the start and end time in order to charge per minute of call but since I am facing some issues with call right now so I decided to go for online meeting as an event and then allow it as a call to teams and afterwards get logs to get start and end time of meeting. Thats all I want.

Answer (score 0):

Copying answer from comments for better understanding:
You can open deeplink using microsoftTeams.executeDeepLink(/*deepLink*/),also You can use join url in the card action and when user clicks on the button he will be redirected to the meeting. You can send card using Graph API could you please check [Send message containing cards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-3-send-message-containing-cards)